# Receive a signal when the window in focus is maximized and when it leaves maximized mode

Tags: linux, bash, gtk, x11, gnome

I'm writing a script that will run as a daemon.
I need to check when there's a maximized window in focus on the screen, and when the window in focus isn't maximized and run my script (bash) in both situations.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: XY problem. What do you really need?

Comment: I need a way to run my script only if the window in focus is maximized, and to run it again if this window leaves the maximized mode.

Comment: Why? What the script is supposed to do? Anyway, subscribe to SubstructureNotifyMask on the root window, and for any event received enumerate all top-level windows with XQueryTree and check if any of them is maximized and in focus.

Comment: From which point you need to launch the script, from GTK (which version 2, 3 ...)? For GTK, you can track "window-state-event" (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.12/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-window-state-event)

Comment: No, this script needs to run as a daemon, window-independent. I mean, this will be a separate "program".
What I'm trying to do:
- Run my script the gnome-shell theme when there's a maximized window in focus;
- Revert to the original theme if there's no maximized window in focus.
And I've no idea on how I could do that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any solution ready to be used out of the box but you can easily accomplish what requested by leveraging [libwnck](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/). In the following a quite basic example that catches any maximization on the current screen:

```
/* gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libwnck-1.0) test.c -o test */

#include <gdk/gdk.h>

#define WNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE
#include <libwnck/libwnck.h>


static void
geometry_changed(WnckWindow *window)
{
    if (wnck_window_is_maximized(window)) {
        g_print("A window has been maximized\n");
    }
}

static void
window_opened(WnckScreen *screen, WnckWindow *window)
{
    g_signal_connect(window, "geometry-changed",
                     G_CALLBACK(geometry_changed), NULL);

    /* Force a geometry-changed emission on already opened windows:
     * remove it if you need to catch only *new* maximizations */
    geometry_changed(window);
}

gint
main(gint argc, gchar *argv[])
{
    GMainLoop *loop;
    WnckScreen *screen;

    gdk_init(&argc, &argv);

    screen = wnck_screen_get(0);
    g_signal_connect(screen, "window-opened",
                     G_CALLBACK(window_opened), NULL);

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);

    return 0;
}
```

### Addendum

If you want to know when the window focus changes, you can connect a callback to the [`active-window-changed`](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/WnckScreen.html#WnckScreen-active-window-changed) signal of the relevant `WnckScreen`, such as in the following untested snippet:

```
static void
active_window_changed(WnckScreen *screen)
{
    WnckWindow *active_window = wnck_screen_get_active_window(screen);
    if (wnck_window_is_maximized(active_window)) {
        g_print("The active window is maximized\n");
    }
}

...
g_signal_connect(screen, "active-window-changed",
                 G_CALLBACK(active_window_changed), NULL);
...
```

Comment: Wow! This is really a great start.
Is there a way to everytime the window in focus changes I check the state of the current window in focus?

Comment: Check the *Addendum* section for the response.

Comment: Thank you! I've done this yesterday, combining the two signals. If you're curious: https://github.com/camporez/dynamic-panel